# Can linear and rotating charges, like rotating spirals, produce similar electromagnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, rotational-dynamics

Do the green charged particles produce a different electromagnetic field than the red charges? They seemingly produce the same motion. Imagine the case to be a line charge. Here they are discretized into particles for easier illustration of the problem. Red particles are moving straight with uniform speed and emerge and disappear (eventually through the third dimension perpendicular to the plane). Green particles are rotating with the same angular speed.

[image: Linear and rotating motion appears similar.]

[Source code](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3sXcD8) of the animation is on Shadertoy.